# Здравствуйте! Проблема с PHP, JS и YandexApi!

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yandex-maps-jsapi, telegram

Нужно какая-либо идея реализации получения расстояния между 2 адресами по дорогам, используя API Яндекса (док-ию почитал, знаю что и как брать в JS). бот на PHP (Использую Telegram-API), АПИ Яндекса только на js, как обмениваться данными?

По поводу передачи данных в js-функцию без понятия, по идее должно сработать echo "func(".$переменная1.",".$переменная2.");"; ? А после возращать в функции значения в PHP по document.write('переменнаяPHP = значение'); ?

Вот такие у меня догадки. Как сделать правильно и что-бы работало? По идее тут должны происходить перезагрузки страницы, что наверное не очень хорошо в случае с ботом, AJAX наверное придется использовать? При передаче данных из JS в PHP работал только с куки просто на сайте и все прекрасно выходило, в такой ситуации я без понятия что делать.

Comment: А вам нужно показывать карту или только узнавать расстояние?

Comment: Только расстояние

Comment: Бот для Телеграма, если это чем-то поможет

Comment: я почитал док-ию и знаю как это сделать, само взаимодействие не знаю как провернуть.

Comment: Условия использования API запрещают так делать, поэтому бесплатная версия не подойдёт, а в коммерческой линейке Яндекса есть HTTP API - там вообще не будет проблем с обменом данными.

Comment: У меня есть ключ, куплено все. По поводу HTTP-API я нашел только ГеоКодер.

Comment: Можно ссылку на этот HTTP-API с помощью которого можно будет получать расстояние? Пожалуйста)

Comment: https://tech.yandex.ru/routing/ - но там отдельная лицензия, надо покупать его, а не JS API

Comment: Я находил то что нужно в MultiRouteModel, вроде так называлось, там был массив routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Браузерный js-код не проигрывается Telegram-сервером.